# Pegar display_name no wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Seguinte, quando um usuario se cadastra em meu site, ele recebe um email de boas vindas, estou utilizando um plugin (BuddyPress) que envia para mim este email de boas vindas, utilizando um filter que o mesmo disponibilizou estou alterando o e-mail de boas vindas para aparecer o display_name do usuario ao invés do email(no corpo da mensagem).

Exemplo: Aparece Olá, eunice@provedor.com, e quero que apareça, Olá, Eunice Negris Lima.(que é o nome que ela se cadastrou)

ID   | display_name
95 | Eunice Negris Lima

Gostaria de saber como pego essa informação do banco ou seja qual função utilizo.

OBrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a variável global $current_user->display_name;